# Linking symbols to fixed addresses on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, gnu, ld

How would one go about linking (some) symbols to specific fixed addresses using GNU ld so that the binary could still be executed as normal in Linux (x86)? There will not be any accesses to those symbols, but their addresses are important.

For example, I'd have the following structure:

```
struct FooBar {
    Register32 field_1;
    Register32 field_2;
    //...
};

struct FooBar foobar;
```

I'd like to link `foobar` to address 0x76543210, but link the standard libraries and the rest of the application normally. The application will then make use of the address of foobar, but will not reference the (possibly non-existent) memory behind it.

The rationale for this request is that this same source can be used on two platforms: On the native platform, `Register32` can simply be a `volatile uint32_t`, but on Linux `Register32` is a C++ object with the same size as a `uint32_t` that defines e.g. `operator=`, which will then use the address of the object and sends a request to a communication framework with that address (and the data) to perform the actual access on remote hardware. The linker would thus ensure the `Register32` fields of the struct refer to the correct "addresses".

Comment: *WHY* would you possibly want to do this?

Comment: On a memory-protected OS there is _NO_ reason to do this.

Comment: This kind of thing is often needed in embedded systems where hardware sits at known specific addresses. 0x76543210 isn't a likely such address, however. ;-)  ld also isn't the friendliest linker to use for such things. There is a syntax for defining symbols from the linker script that helps.

Comment: The OP's intentions seem to go beyond simply accessing hardware that sits at a specific address.  With GCC, something like "struct FooBar *foobar = (struct FooBar*)0x76543210" should be a straightforward way to facilitate hardware access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed address variable in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682697/fixed-address-variable-in-c)

Comment: Also see [relocatable code and object files and shared libraries](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2008-10/msg00183.html) (see Ian lance Taylor's reply).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The suggestion by litb to use `--defsym symbol=address` does work, but is a bit cumbersome when you have a few dozen such instances to map. However, `--just-symbols=symbolfile` does just the trick. It took me a while to find out the syntax of the `symbolfile`, which is

```
symbolname1 = address;
symbolname2 = address;
...
```

The spaces seem to be required, as otherwise `ld` reports `file format not recognized; treating as linker script`.

Answer (score 10):

Try it with

```
--defsym symbol=expression
```

As with this:

```
gcc -Wl,--defsym,foobar=0x76543210 file.c
```

And make foobar in your code an extern declaration:

```
extern struct FooBar foobar;
```

This looks promising. However, it's a bad idea to do such a thing (unless you *really* know what you do). Why do you need it?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the hot tip... GNU LD can do this (assuming the system libs don't need the address you want).  You just need to build your own linker script instead of using the compiler's autogenerated one.  Read the man page for ld.  Also, building a linker script for a complex piece of software is no easy task when you involve the GLIBC too.

Comment: The ld documentation wasn't very useful, at least with only a few hours' study. I tried adapting the compiler's default linker script, but gave up when I noticed it won't link even with the (unedited) extracted default script (while it of course links ok without a linker script).