# Fixed address variable in C

Tags: c, embedded

For embedded applications, it is often necessary to access fixed memory locations for peripheral registers.  The standard way I have found to do this is something like the following:

```
// access register 'foo_reg', which is located at address 0x100
#define foo_reg *(int *)0x100

foo_reg = 1;      // write to foo_reg
int x = foo_reg;  // read from foo_reg
```

I understand how that works, but what I don't understand is how the space for foo_reg is allocated (i.e. what keeps the linker from putting another variable at 0x100?).  Can the space be reserved at the C level, or does there have to be a linker option that specifies that nothing should be located at 0x100.  I'm using the GNU tools (gcc, ld, etc.), so am mostly interested in the specifics of that toolset at the moment.

Some additional information about my architecture to clarify the question:

My processor interfaces to an FPGA via a set of registers mapped into the regular data space (where variables live) of the processor. So I need to point to those registers and block off the associated address space.  In the past, I have used a compiler that had an extension for locating variables from C code.  I would group the registers into a struct, then place the struct at the appropriate location:

```
typedef struct
{ 
   BYTE reg1;
   BYTE reg2;
   ...
} Registers;

Registers regs _at_ 0x100;

regs.reg1 = 0;
```

Actually creating a 'Registers' struct reserves the space in the compiler/linker's eyes.

Now, using the GNU tools, I obviously don't have the *at* extension.  Using the pointer method:

```
#define reg1 *(BYTE*)0x100;
#define reg2 *(BYTE*)0x101;
reg1 = 0

// or
#define regs *(Registers*)0x100
regs->reg1 = 0;
```

This is a simple application with no OS and no advanced memory management.  Essentially:

```
void main()
{
    while(1){
        do_stuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your linker and compiler don't know about that (without you telling it anything, of course). It's up to the designer of the ABI of your platform to specify they don't allocate objects at those addresses.

So, there is sometimes (the platform i worked on had that) a range in the virtual address space that is mapped directly to physical addresses and another range that can be used by user space processes to grow the stack or to allocate heap memory.

You can use the defsym option with GNU ld to allocate some symbol at a fixed address:

```
--defsym symbol=expression
```

Or if the expression is more complicated than simple arithmetic, use a custom linker script. That is the place where you can define regions of memory and tell the linker what regions should be given to what sections/objects. See [here](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/MEMORY.html#MEMORY) for an explanation. Though that is usually exactly the job of the writer of the tool-chain you use. They take the spec of the ABI and then write linker scripts and assembler/compiler back-ends that fulfill the requirements of your platform.

Incidentally, GCC has an [attribute `section`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bsection_007d-variable-attribute-2312) that you can use to place your struct into a specific section. You could then tell the linker to place that section into the region where your registers live.

```
Registers regs __attribute__((section("REGS")));
```

Comment: Actually, the linker does, through a linker script which defines the memory regions available for use.  It defines (for example) .text and .bss regions for constant data and volatile data (RAM), respectively.

Comment: indeed :) in meant to say without doing anything, there is no chance for it to know about that :)

Comment: Does `defsym` really allocate anything at all at a given address? AFAIK it's essentially a linker equivalent of `#define`, you can't even specify the size of the object with it, and it won't prevent the linker to place another variable at the same address.

Comment: it is also possible to say in linker script "place this symbol(s) to that area, or that address", but I don't remember how .

Answer (score 8):

A linker would typically use a linker script to determine where variables would be allocated. This is called the "data" section and of course should point to a RAM location. Therefore it is impossible for a variable to be allocated at an address not in RAM.

You can read more about linker scripts in GCC [here](http://www.xgc.com/manuals/gcc-1750-ug/p5node5.html).

Answer (score 5):

Your linker handles the placement of data and variables.  It knows about your target system through a linker script.  The linker script defines regions in a [memory layout](http://www.xgc.com/manuals/gcc-1750-ug/p5node12.html) such as `.text` (for constant data and code) and `.bss` (for your global variables and the heap), and also creates a correlation between a virtual and physical address (if one is needed).  It is the job of the linker script's maintainer to make sure that the sections usable by the linker do not override your IO addresses.

Answer (score 2):

When the embedded operating system loads the application into memory, it will load it in usually at some specified location, lets say 0x5000. All the local memory you are using will be relative to that address, that is, int x will be somewhere like 0x5000+code size+4... assuming this is a global variable. If it is a local variable, its located on the stack. When you reference 0x100, you are referencing system memory space, the same space the operating system is responsible for managing, and probably a very specific place that it monitors.

The linker won't place code at specific memory locations, it works in 'relative to where my program code is' memory space.

This breaks down a little bit when you get into virtual memory, but for embedded systems, this tends to hold true.

Cheers!

Comment: This is only true for [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) which may or may not be used in a particular embedded system. Most of such system don't even have the OS, the code just lies in ROM and there is no reason to make it position-independent.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the GCC toolchain to give you an image suitable for use directly on the hardware without an OS to load it is possible, but involves a couple of steps that aren't normally needed for normal programs.

1. You will almost certainly need to customize the C run time startup module. This is an assembly module (often named something like `crt0.s`) that is responsible initializing the initialized data, clearing the BSS, calling constructors for global objects if C++ modules with global objects are included, etc. Typical customizations include the need to setup your hardware to actually address the RAM (possibly including setting up the DRAM controller as well) so that there is a place to put data and stack. Some CPUs need to have these things done in a specific sequence: e.g. The ColdFire MCF5307 has one chip select that responds to every address after boot which eventually must be configured to cover just the area of the memory map planned for the attached chip.
2. Your hardware team (or you with another hat on, possibly) should have a memory map documenting what is at various addresses. ROM at 0x00000000, RAM at 0x10000000, device registers at 0xD0000000, etc. In some processors, the hardware team might only have connected a chip select from the CPU to a device, and leave it up to you to decide what address triggers that select pin.
3. GNU ld supports a very flexible linker script language that allows the various sections of the executable image to be placed in specific address spaces. For normal programming, you never see the linker script since a stock one is supplied by gcc that is tuned to your OS's assumptions for a normal application.
4. The output of the linker is in a relocatable format that is intended to be loaded into RAM by an OS. It probably has relocation fixups that need to be completed, and may even dynamically load some libraries. In a ROM system, dynamic loading is (usually) not supported, so you won't be doing that. But you still need a raw binary image (often in a HEX format suitable for a PROM programmer of some form), so you will need to use the objcopy utility from binutil to transform the linker output to a suitable format.

So, to answer the actual question you asked...

You use a linker script to specify the target addresses of each section of your program's image. In that script, you have several options for dealing with device registers, but all of them involve putting the text, data, bss stack, and heap segments in address ranges that avoid the hardware registers. There are also mechanisms available that can make sure that ld throws an error if you overfill your ROM or RAM, and you should use those as well.

Actually getting the device addresses into your C code can be done with `#define` as in your example, or by declaring a symbol directly in the linker script that is resolved to the base address of the registers, with a matching `extern` declaration in a C header file.

Although it is possible to use GCC's `section` attribute to define an instance of an uninitialized `struct` as being located in a specific section (such as `FPGA_REGS`), I have found that not to work well in real systems. It can create maintenance issues, and it becomes an expensive way to describe the full register map of the on-chip devices. If you use that technique, the linker script would then be responsible for mapping `FPGA_REGS` to its correct address.

In any case, you are going to need to get a good understanding of object file concepts such as "sections" (specifically the text, data, and bss sections at minimum), and may need to chase down details that bridge the gap between hardware and software such as the interrupt vector table, interrupt priorities, supervisor vs. user modes (or rings 0 to 3 on x86 variants) and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Typically these addresses are beyond the reach of your process. So, your linker wouldn't dare put stuff there.

Comment: My processor interfaces to an FPGA via a set of registers mapped into the regular data space of the processor.  So I need to point to those registers and block off the associated address space.

Comment: Have you actually run into a situation where there is an overlap? Object code contains relocatable addresses mostly, and they are mapped on to the user's process space at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If the memory location has a special meaning on your architecture, the compiler should know that and not put any variables there.  That would be similar to the IO mapped space on most architectures.  It has no knowledge that you're using it to store values, it just knows that normal variables shouldn't go there.  Many embedded compilers support language extensions that allow you to declare variables and functions at specific locations, usually using `#pragma`.  Also, generally the way I've seen people implement the sort of memory mapping you're trying to do is to declare an int at the desired memory location, then just treat it as a global variable.  Alternately, you could declare a pointer to an int and initialize it to that address.  Both of these provide more type safety than a macro.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on litb's answer, you can also use the `--just-symbols=`{symbolfile} option to define several symbols, in case you have more than a couple of memory-mapped devices. The symbol file needs to be in the format

```
symbolname1 = address;
symbolname2 = address;
...
```

(The spaces around the equals sign seem to be required.)

Answer (score 1):

Often, for embedded software, you can define within the linker file one area of RAM for linker-assigned variables, and a separate area for variables at absolute locations, which the linker won't touch.

Failing to do this should cause a linker error, as it should spot that it's trying to place a variable at a location already being used by a variable with absolute address.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit on what OS you are using. I'm guessing you are using something like DOS or vxWorks. Generally the system will have certian areas of the memory space reserved for hardware, and compilers for that platform will *always* be smart enough to avoid those areas for their own allocations. Otherwise you'd be continually writing random garbage to disk or line printers when you meant to be accessing variables.

In case something else was confusing you, I should also point out that `#define` is a preprocessor directive. No code gets generated for that. It just tells the compiler to textually replace any `foo_reg` it sees in your source file with `*(int *)0x100`. It is no different than just typing `*(int *)0x100` in yourself everywhere you had `foo_reg`, other than it may look cleaner.

What I'd probably do instead (in a modern C compiler) is:

```
// access register 'foo_reg', which is located at address 0x100
const int* foo_reg = (int *)0x100;
*foo_reg = 1;  // write to foo_regint 
x = *foo_reg;  // read from foo_reg
```